# How to get deployment's error messages using SOAP

Tags: apex, deployment, soap-api, metadata-api

I'm developing an app that uses APEX + SOAP API to retrieve and deploy metadata (specifically - objects). I'm using [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to get it done with SOAP. I want to retrieve deployment's details when it fails.

I'm using [checkDeployStatus](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L13298) method to check if deployment is done and to get it's status:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void checkDeployAsyncRequest(String asyncResultId){
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
        MetadataService.DeployResult deployResult = service.checkDeployStatus(asyncResultId, true);

        System.debug(deployResult.Id);
        System.debug(deployResult.errorMessage);
        System.debug(deployResult.errorStatusCode);
    }
```

`errorMessage` and `errorStatusCode` are null:

[image]

Anyway I can get the details in Setup and using Rest API as well:

[image]
[image]

How can I achieve this using SOAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should be in:

```
System.debug(deployResult.details.componentFailures[0].problem);
```

The topLevel `errorMessage` and `errorStatusCode` are for payload problems (e.g. invalid XML or a missing file). Once it starts processing, you need to check componentFailures for error messages.

Comment: Why didn't I think of the fact that the soap result might have the same structure as the rest? I have no idea! Thanks, @sfdcfox :)